# Value Added Tax Is Not Calculated By jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="" id="form-show">
        <table  class="table table-bordered  table-striped table-hover" id='total' style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td> Sum of all </td>
                    <td> Sum of all with discount </td>
                    <td> Final Price </td>
                    <td> Final Price With VAT </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

As you can see I have commented out `// replacing with html` and till now it is working properly but the only problem is that, it does not print out `total_vat` and shows 0 somehow!

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

**Note:** I have skipped some of the codes, if you want to see a particular code, just let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you declare `var total_vat` if you dont use it?

Comment: Can you provide me with a fully working piece of code - I do not want to have to rebuild the whole HTML page. Jquery CDN calls, etc.

Comment: @SergioRodriguez Sure, I'm adding it, stay alert plz

Comment: @ssBarBee I don't understand! **Final Price With VAT** is defined by `#total-vat` and should calculate `total_final + (price_final*cnt) + arzesh_afzoude`. But it returns 0

Comment: When form submits, the page will reload if you don't prevent the default submit event

Comment: checking the code. I will let you know.

Comment: @SergioRodriguez Thanks, my career depends on this

Comment: what jquery version are you using? can you provide me with the HTML header section?

Comment: @SergioRodriguez Yes, just a moment

Comment: @SergioRodriguez version: `jquery.2.2.4.js`

Comment: try this - add: var vat = $("input[name='vat']:checked").val();  if (vat === "on") {
                    var arzesh_afzoude = (price_final*cnt*0.09).toLocaleString();
                } else {
                    var arzesh_afzoude = (0).toLocaleString();console.log(arzesh_afzoude);
                }

Comment: Check the js code you provided for the Js part. That code needs some tlc.

Comment: @KKKKKK OP (aka. Original Post) is incomplete. There are no form controls (ex. `<input>`). There are references to non-existent elements that actually are essential (ex. `#cnt`, `#prc`). Read this article on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the if statement checking for the radio selection with the following code:

```
var vat = $("input[name='vat']:checked").val();
   if (vat === "on") {
       var arzesh_afzoude = (price_final*cnt*0.09).toLocaleString();
  } else {
       var arzesh_afzoude = (0).toLocaleString();
 }
```

you can write it as a one-liner with a ternary operator